# Websocket Connection ErrorERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: websocket, tizen, tizen-web-app

I am currently developing a `tizen app` using a web app.
I have a problem with `web socket` communication, but I can not tell which part is the problem.

Is there anybody who can help with this?

```
try port number 9000,3000,8080
```

> WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:3000/' failed: Error in
>   connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: "Localhost" is a Tizen emulator / device in the context of the application. Does the WS server work on it or on your PC? Please, describe how this configuration looks like.

Answer (score 2):

Could you check this guide page for Tizen Websocket?
https://developer.tizen.org/ko/development/guides/web-application/w3chtml5supplementary-features/communication/websocket

I think.. If you add some codes, it will be helpful to others.